# Why is my polynomial regression only showing on R+?

Tags: python, matplotlib

So I started using Python for a school project and I had to use raw data from a csv file.
Directly drawing curves associated to the data gives a lot of spikes so I decided to use polynomial regressions, however for a reason I can't seem to figure out, the regression doesn't work for negative values in the x-axis. Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv
from csv import reader

X = []
Y = []
with open('rawnacaclcdalpha.csv', 'r') as read_obj:
    csv_reader = reader(read_obj)
    next(csv_reader)
    for row in csv_reader:
         X.append(row[2]) 
         Y.append(row[0]) 

resultX= np.array(X).astype("float")
resultY= np.array(Y).astype("float")

degree = 6
poly_fit = np.poly1d(np.polyfit(resultX,resultY, degree))

xx = np.linspace(0, 26, 100)
plt.plot(xx, poly_fit(xx), c='r',linestyle='-', lw=1.9)
plt.title('Cl en fonction de Alpha')
plt.xlabel('Alpha')
plt.ylabel('Cl')
plt.axis([0, 25, 0, 100])
plt.grid(True)
plt.scatter(resultX,resultY, s=7)

plt.xlim([-20,20])
plt.ylim([-1.1,1.40])

plt.show()
```

I provided a link to a screenshot of what it plots:

[image: current plot]

As you can see the red curve only does half the job.
If someone knows why I'd gladly hear it. Thanks a lot and have a nice day!